# filter rows failing dtype conversion

Tags: python, pandas, string, dtype

I have a pandas dataframe with lot of columns. The dtype of all columns is object because some columns have strings in value. Is there a way to filter out rows into a different dataframe where value in any column is a string and then convert the cleaned dataframe to integer dtype.

I figured out the second part but not able to achieve the first part - filtering out rows if value contains string character like 'a', 'b' etc. for eg. if df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,2,'a',0,3],
    'col2':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'col3':[1,2,3,'45a5',4]
    })
```

This should become 2 dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,2,3],
    'col2':[1,2,5],
    'col3':[1,2,4]
    })

dfError = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':['a',0],
    'col2':[3,4],
    'col3':[3,'45a5']
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this to be an efficient way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ # main dataframe
    'col1':[1,2,'a',0,3],
    'col2':[1,2,3,4,5],
    'col3':[1,2,3,'45a5',4]
    }) 

mask = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna() # checks if couldn't be numeric
mask = mask.any(1) # check rows that couldn't be numeric

df1 = df[~mask] # could be numeric
df2 = df[mask]  # couldn't be numeric
```

Breaking it down:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric) # converts the dataframe into numeric, but this would give us an error for the string elements (like 'a')

df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') # 'coerce' sets any non-valid element to NaN (converts the string elements to NaN).

>>>
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.0     1   1.0
1   2.0     2   2.0
2   NaN     3   3.0
3   0.0     4   NaN
4   3.0     5   4.0

mask.isna() # Detect missing values.
>>>
    col1   col2   col3
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3  False  False   True
4  False  False  False

mask.any(1) # Returns whether any element is True along the rows
>>>
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
```

Comment: Can you please explain what errors='coerce' does. Also I dont know what any does.

Comment: Edited the andswer with an explanation. @fellowCoder

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if there's a performant way to check this. But a dirty way (might be slow) could be:

```
str_cond = df.applymap(lambda x: isinstance(x, str)).any(1)

df[~str_cond]
  col1  col2 col3
0    1     1    1
1    2     2    2
4    3     5    4

df[str_cond]
  col1  col2  col3
2    a     3     3
3    0     4  45a5
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening in lambda and any.

Comment: `applymap` will apply each element in the data frame with the `lambda` where we check if the element is of type `str`. `any(1)` returns true if any element in a row is string, which we can further use to filter data frame.

Comment: Just to confirm. '1' in any represents if any one column. If I had '2' in there it would mean any 2 column. correct? Also what would be the value for all?

Comment: No `1` represents `row` while `0` represents by `column`. So if you put `1` there you get any in each row and if you put `0` there, you get any in each column. I don't think you can put `2` there.

Comment: understood! thanks!